# Custom Meta Box returns no HTML

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I'm trying to write my first plugin and running into an issue with the callback in add_meta_box(). The meta box appears on the custom post type page however there is no content inside.

[image: No html returned from callback]

Here is the relevant code:

```
class MySkills
{
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('init', array('MySkills', 'ip_myskills_register_post_type'));
        add_action('load-post.php', array($this, 'init_metabox'));
        add_action('load-post-new.php', array($this, 'init_metabox'));
    }

    public function init_metabox() {
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array('MySkills', 'skillsmetabox_init'));
        add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_metabox_details'));
    }

    public function skillsmetabox_init() {
        add_meta_box('myskills_meta', 'Proficiency', 'myskills_html');
    }

    public function myskills_html($post) {
        ?>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( basename(__FILE__ ), 'ipmyskills_nonce' ) ?>
        <label for="ipmyskills_input"><?php _e('Enter the proficiency level for this skill (1 to 100)', 'myskill') ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="ipmysills_input" id="ipmyskills_input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ip_myskills_input', true) ) ?>" />
        <?php
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `array( $this, 'myskills_html' )` to the third argument.

```
    public function skillsmetabox_init() {
        add_meta_box( 'myskills_meta', 'Proficiency', array( $this, 'myskills_html' ) );
    }
```

Since this is class method, it should have the `$this` as well.

The same way you did with

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_metabox_details' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix it. Only weird thing though, when I used $this it threw an error and the page didn't load. Adding the class name via plain text though did fixed it.

Any idea why $this is somehow not available in this method?

Comment: Never mind, looks like in the constructor I had 'MySkills', 'init_metabox' instead of $this. Changed it there and was able to use $this in the callback method. Thanks again for the answer.